# mosquitto - Broker won't start with persistence configuration

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

`mosquitto` does not seem to like the following options for persistence.

```
# Persistence configuration
persistence true
persistence_location /data/qos/
persistent_client_expiration 8h
```

The `/data/qos` does exist and permissions have been set.

```
sudo chown mosquitto:mosquitto /data/qos
```

The persistence configuration options are in a file `persist.conf` placed under `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d` directory. Before copying, I am stopping the broker and starting it again after copying using commands like this:

```
sudo service mosquitto stop
sudo service mosquitto start
```

The `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log` does not give any clue about what could be the issue.

So, what's wrong with the options provided above for persistence?

Comment: What happens if you stop the service and manually start `su mosquitto -c mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

Comment: Also are you sure it doesn't start or is it just not creating the persistence file at startup?

Comment: @hardillb I do recall starting `mosquitto` successfully with `/usr/bin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` i.e. without the switch user. Yes, `mosquitto` never started; no processes are listed in `ps -ef | grep mosq`.

BTW, what is procedure in general? Stop broker, copy `.conf` files into `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d` folder and then start broker?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the post above, the persistence configuration options were provided in a separate file - `persist.conf` placed under `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d` directory. However, there are persistence options **already present** in `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`. Once I removed these, the settings in `persist.conf` went through.

It would have been nice of `mosquitto` to warn of such conflicts.

Comment: Mosquitto does flag up duplicate values when it fails to start (at least at v1.4.x) `Error: Duplicate persistence_file value in configuration.`

Comment: Hmm...I think I am at 1.4 as I wanted the compiled version of websockets from Ubuntu ppa. Don't recall that message. Maybe I missed?